# Is /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc. supposed not to exist?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance through VNC but always fail (only grey background). Some [articles](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2-Page-3.html) say we should have a line in `.vnc/xstartup` which reads `exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` But I checked this file and found that this file does not exist at all in EC2 Ubuntu. So if `sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is executed, there should be an error like

```
sh: 0: Can't open  ...
```

I guess that this is the reason why I can not display the desktop of EC2 ubuntu from TightVNC (I can successfully connect). So my question is: is `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` supposed not to exist? If so, what happens if the execution of `sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` fails? If it should exist, what contents should this file contain?

Comment: The file belongs to the [xinit package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xinit), so you may want to install (or reinstall) xinit.

Comment: Yes, I have installed xinit package. I know that by running a command `dpkg -l|grep xinit` and seeing xinit in the results output.

Comment: Then purge it and install it again to get `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: I did, no use.

Comment: Strange. (I still posted an answer to clarify.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the xinit package, the file you mention should be installed.

```
$ dpkg -L xinit | grep xinitrc
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
$
```

If it's not, these commands ought to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get purge xinit
sudo apt-get install xinit
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your method again, this time /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc appeared, with a line ". /etc/X11/Xsession" in it. But I still only get a grey screen in the remote desktop when connecting.

Comment: @user280121: Then the cause for the problem is something else. Can't help with that, I'm afraid.